# Game boy color deleted my game data

Tags: game-boy

I was playing Super Mario land 6 golden coins and collected 5 of the coins. I was in the middle of playing til the screen turned white so I turned it off. When I turned it back, my file was deleted? Why?!?!

Answer (score 4):

This is likely, and unfortunately, a dead battery.

In most older cartridge based games, the only way to keep save data was with a small battery connected inside each cartridge. It doesn't require much power to keep the save data, but 26 years is more than enough to drain them.

You can find [several](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-replace-the-battery-in-a-pokemon-goldsilve/) [guides](http://www.retrocollect.com/Guides/guide-replacing-a-dead-nintendo-game-boy-save-battery.html) on [how to replace these batteries](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Game+Boy+Cartridge+Battery+Replacement/27213) (some brief research suggests that the original GB games might use the slightly smaller **CR1616** battery rather than the CR2025 suggested for GBC games in the guides).

If you are not comfortable changing the battery yourself (it is a bit more involved than swapping out regular batteries), some stores may be able to do this for you for a price. Particularly stores that specialize in vintage video games.